# Network traffic slows down for all processes when a new process connects

Tags: debian, networking

I've seen an interesting problem recently and I don't know if this has to do with Linux, Debian in particular, my kernel configuration, or something else entirely. If I have an existing process sending and receiving traffic over the connected network interface (`wlp60s0` for example), subsequent traffic from other programs over that same interface will slow down drastically. That is, network traffic is effectively monopolized by one process.

As an example, I might have a Youtube video playing and then launch a system update which has hundreds of megabytes to download. Sometimes that Youtube video will hang. Sometimes the system update download will slow to a crawl. Sometimes both.

Has anyone else seen something like this? Is this just an issue with my specific hardware? I switched laptops recently and didn't have this problem with my earlier laptop.

[edit]

The output of `iw dev wlp60s0 link` is:

```
Connected to e4:95:6e:41:2a:7f (on wlp60s0)
SSID: Chiraag-VPN
freq: 2462
RX: 1660850689 bytes (9231360 packets)
TX: 934647909 bytes (6114920 packets)
signal: -52 dBm
tx bitrate: 72.2 MBit/s MCS 7 short GI

bss flags:  short-preamble short-slot-time
dtim period:    2
beacon int: 100
```

[Information from the `wireless-info` script](https://chiraag.nataraj.us/wireless-info.txt).

I've switched entirely to `systemd-networkd` and friends and removed many legacy programs from my laptop. I use a combination of `systemd-networkd`, `systemd-resolved`, and `wpa_supplicant` to manage my networks (hence the script thinks I have no network manager running).

I will try with ethernet later and report back.

Comment: This could be absolutely normal if the new laptop has a WiFi module that has a much lower bitrate than the old one.  What's the output of `iwconfig` and/or does this also happen when you use a wired connection?

Comment: @Fabby I updated the post with the output of `iw dev wlp60s0 link`. I'm not sure if it happens with ethernet since 99% of the time I'm on wireless.

Comment: Please, download [this script](https://github.com/UbuntuForums/wireless-info) run on the WiFi network and provide the output.  Please [edit]  your question to provide this additional info.  *It would be beneficial to know whether it's a WiFi card problem or a system problem, so connecting to a wired network and seeing whether you have the same issue will help diagnose the problem*